# Is there any option to view commit author name and email on Github for a public repository without cloning the repository?

Tags: github

I tried cloning a public repository on GitHub, and then used the `git log` command to view the list of commits along with the name and email of the Author of each commit.

Is there any way to view the same on the GitHub website?

The commits page on GitHub lists the commit details excluding the author name and email specified in the commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information is available through the API, but not the web interface.  The exception is for commits where the email is not associated with any account, in which case the author name is displayed.  This information is, however, available in the patch format from the website, which you can get by appending `.patch` to the commit URL.

It is intentional that this information is not otherwise available, since making email addresses more visible leads to harvesting by spammers and other unsavory parties, such as recruiters.  Of course, these people can already download the data by cloning the repository, but adding a little extra effort tends to cut down on abuse quite a bit.